# How can I automatically add some query parameters to all links in Laravel Blade templates?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 8.
I display some links in Blade templates using the `route()` helper:

```php
    <a href="{{ route('foo', ['bar'=>'baz']) }}">Hello world</a>
```

Which results in something like:

```html
    <a href="https://example.com/foo?bar=baz">Hello world</a>
```

However, I would like to have more query parameters added *automatically* to the url:

```html
    <a href="https://example.com/foo?bar=baz&src=mailing">Hello world</a>
```

Idealy, I would like to activate this feature with a Blade directive

```php
<a href="{{ route('foo', ['bar'=>'baz']) }}">Hello world</a>
<a href="{{ route('cool') }}">Cool!</a>
<a href="{{ route('icecream', ['flavour'=>'strawberry']) }}">Strawberry icecream</a>

<hr>

@withqueryparams(['src'=>'mailing'])
{{-- same code here, but the result will differ --}}
<a href="{{ route('foo', ['bar'=>'baz']) }}">Hello world</a>
<a href="{{ route('cool') }}">Cool!</a>
<a href="{{ route('icecream', ['flavour'=>'strawberry']) }}">Strawberry icecream</a>
@withendqueryparams
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com/foo?bar=baz">Hello world</a>
<a href="https://example.com/cool">Cool!</a>
<a href="https://example.com/icecream/strawberry">Strawberry icecream</a>

<hr>
    
<a href="https://example.com/foo?bar=baz&src=mailing">Hello world</a>
<a href="https://example.com/cool?src=mailing">Cool!</a>
<a href="https://example.com/icecream/strawberry?src=mailing">Strawberry icecream</a>
```

I know how to manually add query parameters to a route.
I know how to define a Blade directives.

However, I don't know how to automatically add query parameters to parsed routes.

Comment: Have you tried `route('foo', ['bar'=>'baz', 'src'=>'mailing'])` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. I want to avoid specifying `'src'=>'mailing'` in all the calls of `route()`.

Comment: Ok. Anyways,  why are u using this style instead of /../../.. default style

Comment: You can't replace content inside... You must use a global function or similar as one user shared

Answer (score 2):

One way is to declare global function .Create a php file. I will name it as `GlobalFunction.php` in the path of `app/Helpers/GlobalFunction.php`

```
<?php

if(!function_exists('queryParam')) {

    function queryParam($routeName,$params=[]){

        $params['src']="mailing";

        return route($routeName,$params);
    }
}
```

Even improve queryParam method like below

```
    function queryParam($routeName,$params=[],$default=['src'=>'mailing']){
            
            return route($routeName,array_merge($params,$default));
   }
```

and in `composer.json` autoload file

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": ["app/Helpers/GlobalFunction.php"]
    },
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`

so in your view

```
 <a href="{{ queryParam('foo',['bar'=>'baz','name'=>'john']) }}">Hello world</a>
```

Comment: I gave +1 to your answer because it helps. But I don't like the idea of replacing the calls of `route()` with something else. Ideally, `route()` itself would be taken through some kind of hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this

```
@php
    $params = ['bar'=>'baz'];
    if (conditions) {
        $params['src'] = 'mailing';
    }
@endphp

<a href="{{ route('foo', $params) }}">Hello world</a>
```

Comment: Yes... but not really. I modified the examples in my question. Hope it's more clear now.